# What's the difference between working in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $\mathbb{Q}$ in this exercise?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Given those three vectors in $\mathbb{Q}$: $v_1 = (1, 1, 1)$, $v_2 = (1, 2, 0)$, $v_3 = (1, 3, -2)$, verify they span $\mathbb{Q}^3$.

What is the difference between a similar request, and an identical exercise in which the given vectors are given in $\mathbb{R}$, asking for if they span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I mean, I know the difference is given becaue we work in different fields, but besides this, are there other differences?

Comment: Do you mean how would the solutions to both exercices differ ?

Comment: @Digitallis Yes, that too! (and any other difference :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular example, it is equivalent. Indeed you can show that the rank is independent of the field extension. This means (to make it simpler) that if you have a matrix $M$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ of size $n \times n$, it defines two  linear endomorphisms:

- One in $\mathbb{Q}^n$, let's call it $M_\mathbb{Q}$.
- One in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let's call it $M_\mathbb{R}$.

Now there is a very useful (but not necessarily intuitive) result, that can be verified through the use of the determinant:

> $\operatorname{rank}_\mathbb{Q} M_\mathbb{Q} = \operatorname{rank}_\mathbb{R} M_\mathbb{R}$.

This is cool but how is it linked to your exercise?
Just take the concatenate matrix given by your three vectors, its rank is the same in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as in $\mathbb{Q}^3$ so your vectors span $\mathbb{Q}^3$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space and span $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

**Beware** this is true only because your coefficients are in $\mathbb{Q}$, it would not work if you had something like $\sqrt{2}$ in your vectors.

Here is a more advanced version.

> Let's $\mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{L}$ be a field extension (e.g. $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$) and let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space of finite dimension. We define the scalar extension ("induced $\mathbb{L}$-vector space) by
> $$V_\mathbb{L} = V \otimes_\mathbb{K} \mathbb{L}$$
> Then any linear endomorphism $\phi \in \mathcal{L}_\mathbb{K}(V)$ induces a linear endomorphism $\tilde{\phi} \in \mathcal{L}_\mathbb{L} (V_\mathbb{L})$ given by $\tilde{\phi}(v \otimes \lambda) = \phi(v) \otimes \lambda$, and we have
>
> - $\det_\mathbb{K} (\phi) = \det_\mathbb{L} (\tilde{\phi})$
> - $\operatorname{rank}_\mathbb{K} (\phi) = \operatorname{rank}_\mathbb{L} (\tilde{\phi})$
> - $\chi_\phi = \chi_{\tilde{\phi}}.$

Comment: Ahh, the last phrase really clarified everything! (The rest was also clear). Thank you so much!

Comment: No pb, this can be confusing at first :)

Comment: @Numb3rs although, if you haven't seen it already, you shouldn't use this result yet, but it can be quite useful to keep it in mind, especially for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ once you get to reduction.